# Unique ID for Row of a Set in One Table

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, unique-constraint

I know the title is a little weird but what I actually want to do is simple. In my Postgres db a user creates a profile and uploads an image.

```
user_id: 1, photo_id: 1
```

Now a second user makes a profile and uploads two images.

```
user_id: 2, photo_id: 1, photo_id: 2
```

In my photos table, how can a create a unique identifier out of the combination of user_id and photo_id? Neither are unique in the table but their combination should be.

Comment: Why *aren't* there unique IDs for each user and each photo? Are the users and photos stored in their own tables? If not, how are they stored?

Comment: Each has its own table, but a user can have many photos. Something in my previous attempts at this had set a unique constraint on the user_id column in photos, which would throw an error if a user uploaded more than one photo. As for why not, it was a business concern and it's not my favorite choice but it will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, `photo_id` should be unique on the table.** Ignoring sound practice however, you can still do this with a composite `PRIMARY KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
  user_id  int,
  photo_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, photo_id)
);

INSERT INTO photos (user_id,photo_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,2);

--duplicate already exists
INSERT INTO photos (user_id,photo_id) VALUES (1,1);
```

Composite natural PRIMARY KEY's are not bad, however I'm not a fan of having them on multiple surrogate keys. If you're going to create an ID, may as well make it unique.

Comment: @EvanCarol oh man sorry, user error. your solution is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!